# Trying to convert a list of arrays into an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, web-scraping

So I've been doing some array manipulation recently, and I've run into some trouble. First off, here's my code:

```
from numpy import array, transpose, reshape, insert, delete, array_split, append
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from requests import get

html = get(source["Financial Data"]).text
html = bs(html,"lxml")         #Gets the html data for scraping

table = html.find("table",class_="mytables")
table = [i for i in [[p.text for p in i] for i in table.find_all("tr")] if i!=[]] #Gets the data to be scraped and places it in list form.

table = array_split(table,10) #Splits the data

values = array()
for i in range(len(table)):    #Transposes the data to a flatter form and strips the headings column
    table[i][0][1] = table[i][0][0][-10:]
    table[i] = delete(table[i],0,axis=1)
    table[i] = table[i].transpose() 

for i in range(len(table)): #Should create a new array composed of other arrays so that it's presented in tabular form.
    values = append(values,table[i][0],axis=0)
```

`table` gives me this:

[image]

Which is basically a list with some arrays inside it. Now I want to convert the data within it to something like this:

[image]

Note, the data in the second picture is different. I just want to give you an idea of how I want the end result to look like. Essentially, all the arrays should be layered on top of one another to give an end result as above. However, my end result for values is this:

[image]

[image]

Which is not what I want at all. The arrays were simply added vertically. How do I get where I want?

Comment: i guess, you are looking for [numpy.vstack](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html)

Comment: @luigigi it did exactly what I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: How did your code run with this line `values = array()`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
values = append(values,table[i][0],axis=0)
```

use:

```
values = append(values,table[i][0],axis=1)
```

Comment: Repeated `np.append` in a loop is bad form, even when it works (getting the initial `values` array is tricky if you don't understand dimensions).  With `axis` `np.append` is essentially a `np.concatenate` call.